# asp .net mvc 4 async task updating status on page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

I'm wondering if it's even possible to do:

A long-time operation - console app, doing some stuff, or async task called from controlled.

And I want to show user progress while it's executing. Maybe some additional info, like execution log, or so.

Any ideas? Is that possible to implement that with asp .net MVC 4? What is the best way?

Comment: Yes you can write asynchronous  methods in asp.net mvc apps

Comment: Rohit, yes, but how then I pass current progress to page and show it to user if current thread will be in 'awaiting' state?

Comment: You will have two threads ui thread and background thread.Till background thread completes its operation you can show progress icon in ui thread